# Extract data from dataframe-column without unnesting

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I have a dataframe-column and usually I would unnest it, but I get this: `Error: Input must be list of vectors` . Then it would be easy to select the columns I want.

Is there a way around this? Column 5 is my dataframe-column. I want to extract one of these from every row and have thousands of rows:

`df[[5]][[1]]$term` and `df[[5]][[1]]$estimate`

If anyone knows of a similar public dataset I could use to make a reprex for this, let me know. I'm having trouble recreating the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try -

```
df$term <- sapply(df[[5]], `[[`, "term")
df$estimate <- sapply(df[[5]],`[[`, "estimate")
```